# Basemap m(lats,lons) to svg cx and cy

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib-basemap

I am creating an SVG image of the world with basemap on which I plot the city of Berlin as a "control point" (because I would like to place a circle there manually ... so I have a reference).

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Berlin & New York & Sydney
lats = [52.516667] #[52.516667, 40.730610]
lons = [13.388889] # [13.388889, -73.935242]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15/2))
m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, resolution='c')
m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.75)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#e6f5ff')                
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#e6f5ff', linewidth=1, color='#000000') # Ocean          

x,y = m(lons,lats)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color='r', markersize=5)

plt.savefig("basemap.svg", figsize=(24,12))
plt.show()
```

In a next step, I would like to manually place a circle on the SVG image by editing the code of the SVG file that I've created. This can be done by introducing the following code before `</svg>` at the end of the SVG image code.

```
<circle fill="blue" cx="250" cy="470" r="2"/>
```

How can I determine the correct value for cx and cy with my Python code to place the blue dot where Berlin is located?

I figured I have a `mapWidth = 1080` and a `mapHeigth = 540` and `xMax = 33973600` and `yMax = 17231000`.

In this way I could calculate `cx = mapWidth - x/xMax*mapWidth` and analogously `cy = mapHeigth - y/yMax*mapHeigth`. However, this does not place the blue dot at the correct position also not if I consider a bottom and left margin of 72 and 152 pt, respectively. Any ideas?

Comment: You can draw circle on the map before saving the image (with `matplotlib.pyplot.circle` for example). Not sure that doing it by hand is really good, chiefly when you're dealing with projections. Why do you want to do it by hand ? Are you processing the `svg` outside python ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to process the svg outsid eof python. I am drawing some arrows manually to create a flow map.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you really need a solution, I will give you one way to do.

**NOTE** : I do not encourage you to manipulate `.svg` file by hand. However, if there are no choice, let's do it !

The solution **assumes** that the non python process do not change the file in the form.

To overcome the creation of `.svg` file (black box for me at least), you can just create another image plotting the expected coordinates, save the image as temporary `.svg` file, find the coordinates points (on the `.svg` file) and finally add them to your initial map file.

I define 3 methods:
- `createMap` to draw a map and save the output as `.png` file
- `get_svg_coordinates`: create a temporary map (`.svg` file), read point coordinates, remove temporary file, return point coordinates.
- `add_circle`: draw circle on existing `.svg` map file.

Here the code: (working example)

```
# Import modules
import os
import re
# os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\Users\...\Library\share'
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def createMap(lats, lons, color='r', figure_name="basemap.svg", show=False):
    """ Create a map from points coordinates + export to .csv file
    Arguments
        :param lats: latitudes
        :param lons: longitudes
        :param color='r': color points
        :param figure_name="basemap.svg": name output file
        :param show=False: show the map
    """
    # Same code as yours
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15/2))
    m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, resolution='c')
    m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.75)
    m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#e6f5ff')
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#e6f5ff', linewidth=1, color='#000000')  # Ocean

    x, y = m(lons, lats)

    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color=color, markersize=5)
    plt.savefig(figure_name, figsize=(24, 12))

    if show: plt.show()


def get_svg_coordinates(lat, lon, color='#ff0000', figure_temp_name="tmp_figure.svg"):
    """ Create a temporary file using the createMap function
        Find the point coordinates inside (using regex check)
        Remove temporary csv file
    Arguments
        :param lat: new point latitude
        :param lon: new point  longitude
        :param color='#ff0000': point color
        :param figure_temp_name="tmp_figure.svg": temp file name
    """
    createMap(lat, lon, color=color, figure_name=figure_temp_name)

    with open(figure_temp_name, "r") as f:
        # read file
        content = f.read()  
        # Find x - y values (pattern ' x=' is unique is you are using 1 point)
        x = re.findall(r'<use.*x=\"(\d*\.*\d*)\"', content)
        y = re.findall(r'<use.*y=\"(\d*\.*\d*)\"', content)

    # remove file
    os.remove(figure_temp_name)
    return x, y


def add_circle(map_file_name, x, y):
    """ Draw circle at the end of file
    Arguments:
        :param map_file_name: filename (adding circle)
        :param x: x coordinates (results of get_svg_coordinates method)
        :param y: y coordinates (results of get_svg_coordinates method)
    """
    with open(map_file_name, "r+") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        # get number of lines in file
        for i, l in enumerate(content):
            pass
        # Add content
        content.insert(i, '<circle fill="blue" cx="{0}" cy="{1}" r="2"/>'.format(x[0], y[0]))
        f.seek(0)                   # file pointer locates at the beginning to write the whole file again
        f.writelines(content)       # rewrite file


# Berlin & New York & Sydney
lats = [52.516667]  # [52.516667, 40.730610]
lons = [13.388889]  # [13.388889, -73.935242]

# create your initial svg map
map_file_name = "basemap.svg"
createMap(lats, lons, figure_name=map_file_name)

# Find new position point on svg file
# Define coordinates points
NewYork_lat = 40.730610
NewYork_long = -73.935242
x, y = get_svg_coordinates(NewYork_lat, NewYork_long)
add_circle(map_file_name, x, y)
```

Note:

- I'm not familiar with `.svg` file. To answer the question, I add `<circle fill="blue" cx="???" cy="???" r="2"/>` at the end of the file as expected. However, it's maybe better to identify the whole DOM `<g id="line2d_1">` and copy past it.
- The snippet works for one image, I let you generalise for a set of point.

Comment: Really, to me it looks like it's been a lot of effort so thank you for your time!